# A word for 'closing eyes'

Tags: verbs, adverbs

So I'm writing a narrative and my character has to close her eyes. However, the word 'close' seems to just give off the visual that she is gently/lightly closing her eyes. I want to do the opposite of that. I have tried using 'shutting her eyes', but I need something more descriptive.

Are there any suggestions as to what I should use? Maybe like an adverb or different verb that I should use instead. I'll appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: She clamped her eyes shut.

Comment: *Snapped*, *slammed*, *clapped*. Short of providing a long list of synonyms, is there any other information you can provide that would help narrow this down?

Comment: @JasonBassford my character is in a situation where she has to close her eyes because she was suddenly submerged in water.

Comment: @JGN Please look again at Ruakh's "closing her eyes tight, or squeezing her eyes shut…" both of which are standard; prolly stock phrases.

Equally, Jason's "Snapped, slammed, clapped…" should do your trick and as he said, short of providing a long list of synonyms, is there any other information you can provide that would help narrow this down?

Answer (score 2):

You can say *closing her eyes tight*, or *squeezing her eyes shut*.

Merriam-Webster [defines *squeeze one's eyes shut*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/squeeze%20one%27s%20eyes%20shut) as "to close one's eyes very tightly".